How to use FQDN with SQL Merge Replication
I have being using IP address to establish connection with Merge Publication - and has being working fine for years.
However - I have now been told that I must use FQDN in order to get thru on Zscaler
How can I implement this ?
I tried  putting the FQDN in the .PublisherAddress subscription parameter e.g. merger.PublisherAddress = the FQDN.
But this just returns 'Unable to connect to Distributor' error.
